# kinect gesture recognition using neural network

Tags: neural-network, kinect-sdk, recurrent-neural-network, kinect.toolbox

we can achieve gestures using kinect,
I am thinking to get images through kinect and then apply neural network on it, to get more accuracy.
is it good approach or i am thinking in wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.visualgesturebuilder.aspx ???

Comment: there is no neural network involved in it. i need to apply neural network on the stream of the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using neural network to recognize human gesture is a good idea, and some guys have published their [result](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6690908/?arnumber=6690908).

Comment: @naveedshah I haven't used kinect, but familiar with neural networks like CNN for image classification.

Comment: how to apply CNN on the stream(video) instead of the image?

Comment: You cannot run CNN on video directly. If you want to build training data set, I suggest you can extract the image from video 10 FPS with the corresponding label(maybe the gesture class). If you try to test your CNN on a video, you must extract a single frame and run CNN on it, then the next frame.